# Photo Interaction Bug: Actions Executed on Initial Selection Instead of Current Photo

Tags: java, android, action, sharing

"If I click on any photo and start swiping left or right, and then click on 'save,' 'share,' or 'set as wallpaper,' it executes the action on the first photo I clicked."

"I'm using Java code on the Android Studio platform."

Update the onInterceptTouchEvent() method